# How to uninstall Redash

Tags: uninstallation, redash

My current installation of Redash is somehow corrupted (installing it in a new PC worked fine so I know my local copy is broken), and I want to basically remove it fully and install it again.

I cannot find any documentation of how to uninstall it,

- I don't find it installed as a service
- I don't find it installed as a application

So how do I reinstall it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the redash installation folder will uninstall the redash but if your installation executable is damaged then reinstalling it again alone might not help.

Check if you have any errors with your supervisor demon:

This supervisor demon is automatically started on port number 9001 on your local machine.

Go to **http://127.0.0.1:9001/** and see if all the services/workers are up.

If there are any errors post back the log here.

Answer (score 0):

Check if redash has created dir - /opt/redash/, Remove it if exists.
 Run this bash for re-install - https://github.com/getredash/redash/blob/master/setup/ubuntu/bootstrap.sh